# How to check if a given regex is invalid

Tags: javascript, regex

I know it doesn't happen often, but every so often, you get regex that is invalid and as I'm making a find and replace program I was wondering how would you test for such invalid regex.

Comment: What does "invalid" mean? Also, have you tried anything at all? [ask] page and [FAQ] are helpful for asking better questions

Comment: Invalid means regex that would break in console. What have I tried? Well I tried doing a try-catch and that worked, but I was wondering if there was a simpler solution

Comment: Try-catch is the way to go, if you don't bother showing the user the break down of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/).

If you have any parse/semantic errors in your regex, it will highlight the exact position for you and tell you what's wrong.

If you are trying to catch logic errors, it will give you a visualization of your regex and allow you to walk through a match step-by-step so you can pinpoint where your regex isn't behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always test your javascript regex using this tool - http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

The page takes regex, your string and shows you the match. This way, you can validate and also test your regex for a given string.